# VB 2010 calculator using multiple user inputs - 'conversion from string to integer is not valid'

Tags: string, vb.net, integer

As I start to type more than 1 number in the first textbox (txtCurBat) it crashes and gives me an error message in the code:

> **InvalidCastException was unhandled**
>
> Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

(this appears next to the line where I marked /*)

The purpose of the program:

To perform calculations while making changes to the text boxes and give output in one label. As you make changes, output changes at the same time.

Here is the subroutine with the error. Please help.

```
Private Sub txtCurBat_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtCurBat.TextChanged
    Dim curBat As Integer = 1
    Dim totalBat As Integer = 1
    Dim TotalDam As Integer = 1
    Dim totalNeededDam As Integer = 1
    Dim damPerBat As Integer = 1
    Dim desAverDam As Integer = 1
    Dim approxBat As Integer = 1
    Dim curDam As Integer = 1
    Dim curAvDam As Integer = 1


    curBat = txtCurBat.Text
    approxBat = txtApproxBat.Text /*
    curAvDam = txtCurAvDam.Text
    desAverDam = txtDesAvDam.Text


    curDam = curBat * curAvDam
    totalBat = curBat + approxBat
    TotalDam = totalBat * desAverDam
    totalNeededDam = TotalDam - curDam
    damPerBat = totalNeededDam / approxBat

    lblOutput.Text = damPerBat

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: So what's in `txtApproxBat.Text`?

Comment: user input in the textbox, integer

Comment: Clearly it's not an integer. Otherwise, you'd get the error first on the line before that, which does the same operation. Once again, what **exactly** is in the textbox? If you want help, provide the details (especially when someone asks you to do so).

Comment: i don;t know why it gives me error message next to it. all it says is what I already typed in my question, and it gives some links of troubleshooting.

Comment: nothing is in the textbox. It should be an integer. Its a user input which I cant test because the program crashes

Comment: cant understand your question thats why i cant tell whats **exactly** is in there and "provide the details". Its just empty.

Comment: OK, an empty string cannot be converted to an integer; therefore the exception. Turn on Option Strict in the project properties on the compile tab. It will save you many runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert an empty string to anything but an empty string. If the string is empty then replace it by a "0".

You can also use something like this

```
        If Integer.TryParse(xString, Result) Then
          Dim x As Integer= 2 * Result 
            'do something
        End If
```